# HP DL380 G4 don't boot after unplug and plug again power

Tags: boot

After an unexpected power off (power cord unplug or main power breakdown), my server HP DL 380 G4 don't reboot POST. I just see hard drive led initialization blink and after nothing.
But if I keep my server unplug during approximatively 12 hours, after I can power on and boot is OK.
Someone can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you contacted HP about this?

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem on motherboard. NVRam lost configuration and don't accept to be cleared, even if I use the switch position 6.
I replaced the motherboard and now all is good.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If it has two power supplys, try to remove one of them.

Comment: I tried, none effect, always the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Got a hardware maintenance contract? if so use it, if not look around for parts or a new server - I think something's popped, it'll be hard to diagnose without parts. Sorry dude.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was an issue with HP ProLiant servers when the power had issues.  This is from the US/Canada site but assume it applies worldwide.

[HP Fix](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=ca&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=397634&swItem=MTX-UNITY-I21055&prodNameId=3288132&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=3)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my server reboot automatically, when it is right. In my case, it don't want to boot even if I push power button.

Comment: I think I need more info around the question. Your serevr had an unexpected power out and then would not reboot until you had it off for 12 hours? Is that correct?